# time left script using php

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I am doing a website where I collect the time and date from the users when they create an event...once they create it, I want to show something like this in 
http://www.groupon.com/washington-dc/ (check time left to buy). i there any direct way in php/mysql. also how to handle the time zone? if a person from california is seeing the event , he/she shouldn't see the same "time left" like NY users...how to handle this?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to always storing date/time in database in UTC timezone. Later you can convert it to user's time zone by php(based on user's location if you store it somewhere) or on client-side using javascript(using client's machine timezone).

Comment: thanks.do you have any link where i can see some examples? i am not an expert but i can do it if i see some examples..i searched many places but i see some things which is not what i want.

Comment: Sorry, don't have examples at hand. For js take a look on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp You can create Date object using UTC time and display it according to user machine's time zone (I think it's safe to assume that most if not all users have timezone set up)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create a static countdown time using PHP and MySQL, but in order to count down the hours, minutes, and seconds, I think your best option is going to be to use JavaScript.

In order to handle the time zones, I think what you could do is store the event's time in the same timezone for each user, regardless of where they are. For example, to set each user's time zone as UTC, use the following:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); ?>
```